# Can we use elastic search for consistent results?

Tags: elasticsearch

Can we use elastic search for consistent results? How frequent the consistency might change?

Let's say I want to retrieve pages of data based on sorted time. How frequent could the specific page results go inconsistent? Because I am sorting by time, is there a possibility for the results to be inconsistent here?

EDIT-1
Eg:
I have a document containing multiple fields. One of the field is timestamp. And in our application, timestamp is always unique for any given document. I want to sort the documents based on timestamp. Now, my question is, if I keep asking for different pages of documents sorted by created time (Let's assume no new documents got added).. will the requested page always contains the same/consistent set of results?

Comment: it would be better to add some example to make it more clear.

Comment: Added an example of my usecase. Thanks

Comment: afaik, if timestamp is unique across the documents then sort will be consistent. results could get inconsistent across queries if there were documents with same timestamp

Comment: awesome. as simple as that. I was waiting for the confirmation from your expertise. After I posted my question last-night, I got to find information about inconsistencies in "bouncing results" section under https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_search_options.html

Comment: The above link really helped me understand why would there be inconsistencies. Thank for your quick response @marxin.